# Static library issue

Tags: iphone, ios, static-libraries

I'm creating a static library with some class files, and the library is creating well  but if I install to library to another new Xcode project it showing error and the error is as follows ,

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/rajesh/Desktop/Quntiles/01-03-2013/ConnectionExample-1/libAVTEmployee.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/rajesh/Desktop/Quntiles/01-03-2013/ConnectionExample-1/libAVTEmployee.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVTEmployee", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in XMLParser-E51A1142A3EEED70.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can any one please help me, how can I fix this issue so that I can use the my static library in my new project ,

I'm using Xcode 4.6 version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your static library was created or compiled using an older version of XCode that didn't support `armv7s` architecture. Open the static library project and make sure that `Architectures` contains armv7 and armv7s architectures and `Build Active Architectures Only` is set to `No` under `Build Settings`.

[image: static library configuration]